# Determine an order $q$ subgroup in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Lemma: Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix over a field $F$. If $A$ is not a scalar multiple of the identity matrix, then $A$ is similar to
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -d\\
1 & t
\end{pmatrix}

For a linear transformation $T: (\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$, we know that $T \in GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$. $T^q=I$, where $q<p$ and $p,q >2$, $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. This implies that the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ for $T$ divides $x^q-1$.

Moreover, there exist some non-zero vector $v \in (\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$ which is not an eigen vector of $T$ and the pair $\{v, T(v)\}$ forms a basis of $(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$. The matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis has the form
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a\\
1 & b
\end{pmatrix}.

This is similar to $A$ (i.e. a=-d, b=t).Based on the above information regarding $T$ and $p,q$, can I determine possible values for $a,b$? In other words, how can I determine possible values for $a,b$ such that $T$ represents a generator of an order $q$ subgroup in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$?

$q$ can divide $p^2-1$. i.e. $q|(p-1)$ or $q|(p+1)$.

Comment: Are you asking for a subgroup of order $q$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$?

Comment: Yes @Haran I'm referring to a subgroup of order $q$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$

Comment: $A=\pmatrix{a&b\\c & d}$ has order $q$ iff $(x-a)(x-d)-bc$ divides $(x^q-1)^2$ but not $(x-1)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Bbb F_{p^2}$ be the quadratic extension of $\Bbb F_p$ and let $\langle\lambda\rangle=\Bbb F_{p^2}^*$. Presumably, $q\;\Big\vert\;|\Bbb F_{p^2}^*|=p^2-1$ and therefore $\Bbb F_{p^2}^*$ contains a size $q$ cyclic subgroup. Let $a=-\alpha\bar{\alpha}\;,\;b=\alpha+\bar{\alpha}$ so that
$$\mathbf A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-\alpha\bar{\alpha}\\1&\alpha+\bar{\alpha}\\\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\alpha=\lambda^{\frac{p^2-1}{q}}$. Now, $\mathbf A,\mathbf D$ are similar as they have the same characteristic polynomial $$\chi(x)=x^2-(\alpha+\bar{\alpha})x+\alpha\bar{\alpha}$$
Therefore, $\langle\mathbf A\rangle,\langle\mathbf D\rangle$ are conjugate size $q$ cyclic $\text{GL}(2,p^2)$ subgroups but with $\langle\mathbf A\rangle\subseteq\text{GL}(2,p)$.

Comment: Thank you very much @OliverKayende can I also please clarify what is meant by "OP" when you say "...results in the OP.." in the very first paragraph?

Comment: Also, for a known value of $p$ and $q$, say $p=5 , q=3$ or $p=11, q=5$, how can I use the above idea to find the matrix $A$ or $D$?

Comment: Thanks a lot @OliverKayende

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika. You are very welcome. I enjoyed your question. By OP I mean  "original post". Find a cyclic generator of $\lambda\in\Bbb F_{p^2}^*$ (no closed formula for this), raise it to the power $\frac{p^2-1}{q}$ and use this result and its conjugate on the main diagonal to construct $\mathbf D$.

Comment: Thank you so much @OliverKayende we have to find a an element which will generate $\lambda$? or a generating element of $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}^*$ and take it as  $\lambda$? I have posted a new question regarding this in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3876357/determining-conjugacy-classes-of-prime-order-q-in-gl-2-mathbbz-p please be kind enough to advice me. Thanks a million!

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika. I made some edits, corrections and shortened the post. Please take a look.

Comment: thank you very very much. It is very clear now. I'll check my computations with it now

Comment: another one small question @OliverKayende: in the previous version of the answer you have taken $a=\lambda(1-\lambda), b=1$, when taking $\lambda,\bar{\lambda}$ as the distinct roots. I understand that $a$ can be written like that if we take $b=1$. Can we set the value of $b$ to a particular value like $1$ like that and rewrite the value of $a$ in terms of that and substitute those values in the matrix $A$?

Comment: Then perhaps we can set the value of $b=-1$ and take $a=-\lambda(\lambda-1)$? I'm asking since I'm testing for some values and it is easy if we can really have $b=-1$ in matrix $A$. Many many thanks!!!

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika. Yes, fixing $b$, say $b=1$, makes the task easier. But when $b=1$ we have $a=\alpha(1-\alpha)$ where $\text{ord}(\alpha)=q$.

Comment: Yes it is true, but I'm studying some patterns in the semidirect products. @OliverKayende then if $b=-1$ I can continue easily, whatever the value of $a$ is. But how can I justify that I can fix the value of $b$ to $-1$ if possible to $-1$ as well?

Comment: Can it represent all the matrices of the form of $A$, when I fix the value of $b$?(no matter what the value of $a$ is) Thanks a lot @OliverKayende

Comment: Can I please only clarify @OliverKayende fixing a value for $b$ will only represent some matrices of type $A$, or does it stand as a general representation ?(i.e. is it ok if I use a matrix with b=-1, for any $A$?)

Comment: If can, how do I justify it? Thanks a million!

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika. Our original goal was on constructing matrices in $\text{GL}(2,p)$ of the form $\mathbf A=\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\1&b\\\end{pmatrix}$, call this Form 1, and of prime multiplicative order $q$ where $q\;\Big\vert\;p^2-1$. We now know that matrices of the form $$\mathbf A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-\alpha\bar{\alpha}\\1&\alpha+\bar{\alpha}\\\end{pmatrix}\;\;\;\;(\text{Form}\;2)$$ have Form 1 and order $q$  whenever $\text{ord}(\alpha)=q$ where $\alpha\in\Bbb F_{p^2}^*$. Moreover, $\it{all}$ matrices of form 1 and order $q$ must have form 2.

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika. All matrices of form 1 and order $q$, $q\;\Big\vert\;p+1$, have form 2.

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika. To see how to go about proving this assume $\text{ord}(\mathbf A)=q$ and $\mathbf A=\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\1&b\\\end{pmatrix}$. The characteristic polynomial of $\mathbf A$ has either two roots in $\Bbb F_p^*$ or two conjugate roots in $\Bbb F_{p^2}^*$. Given non-zero eigenvalue $\alpha$ and corresponding non-zero eigenvector $\mathbf x$ then $\mathbf x=\mathbf A^q\mathbf x=\alpha^q\mathbf x$ and therefore $\text{ord}(\alpha)\;\big\vert\;q\;\nmid p-1$. Therefore, the eigenvalues are distinct conjugates which yields form 2.

Comment: Thank you very very much @OliverKayende but still we can't confirm whether we can fix the value of $b$ right? But we can prove the existence of form 2 as above :) And however if $q|p-1$ also, we can have form 1 even though we can't have form 2, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks a lot again @OliverKayende ! :) :) Your answers and comments have been very useful